# Google API (Sheets) API Error code 403. Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: python, google-sheets, anaconda, google-sheets-api

I am trying out a project where I am able to use python (im using jupyter notebooks on Anaconda) to read data from google sheets. I watched a few videos and guides and replicated the code. However, I am unable to get the code to work correctly

```
import pandas as pd
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('test.json',scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
data = gc.open('TEST').sheet1
print(data.get_all_records())
```

The error message I got was

```
APIError: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
 }
}
```

Any advice on what I should do?

Answer (score 7):

Authentication scopes allow your application to perform certain actions on the service using OAuth2 authentication. When using google APIs, please refer to the [Google API scopes sheet](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes).

See the Google Sheets API V4 related scopes in the below image.Please make sure not to give extra permissions which could affect the security of your application.

[image]

**Please Note**: Since you are planning on changing the scopes, first delete the `token.json` file created in the local project folder, and then allow access to your application again. This will create a new `token.json` file.

Answer (score 3):

i saw a new way on github using a google lib. Doing this

```
import gspread
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file('client_secret.json', scopes=scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)
```

i used this link: https://github.com/burnash/gspread

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to allow access to the sheet for the email (client_email) that stated in credentials.json, that you downloaded from API dashboard:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "private_key_id": ".........",
  "private_key": .........
  "client_email": "getgooglesheets@xxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "..............",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  .......
}
```

I mean, you should go to your Google Sheet file and manually allow access for this email there. That worked fine in my case.

Comment: that worked out for me too in golang. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me, read for example documents from google sheet

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('my-drive.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
# Make sure you use the right name here.
sheet = client.open("contactos-xxx").sheet1

# Extract and print all of the values
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
print(list_of_hashes)
```